# Woocommerce Product_cat for current category page

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

i am trying to set a category page up but i want to show the product that are in that category currently. i dont want to make a php template for each category

at the minute it is set as this

```
<?php $args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'product_cat'    => 'cat1'
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    ?>
```

is there a way to make the product_cat to find the products for the page its currently on?

my product code is :

```
<div class="row products-range search-space">   
                <?php  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    global $product;?>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                        <div class="box">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href=""><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x400" class="img-responsive center-block" /></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="info">
                                <h3><a href="product-detail.html"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>13cm Reflex Foam/7cm Top layer</li>
                                    <li>Mains Isolation/Battery backup</li>
                                    <li>5 Year warranty on Mattress and Frame</li>
                                    <li>FREE INSTALLATION and Demonstration</li>
                                </ul>
                                <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" href="<?php get_permalink();?>">View</a>
                            </div>  
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile;
                                wp_reset_query();?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get category info using

```
$category = get_queried_object();


                $cpt_cat = $category->term_id;
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'posts_per_page' => 10,
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                            'field'    => 'term_id',
                            'terms'    => $cpt_cat,
                        ),
                    ),
                );

                // Custom query.
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    global $wpdb;

                    /* Start the Loop */
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                            ?>
                            // Put your HTML stuff here
                            <?php
                        }
                    endwhile;
                    // Restore original post data.
                    wp_reset_postdata();


                } ?>
```

And use category id/slug in your query for result.

Hope this will help!

Comment: where I'm I adding this

Comment: In your **texonomy** template query

Comment: I have the category information on the page I want to the pull the products in that category now look at my updated code.

Comment: Checked your code. Is it product archive file right ?

Comment: I am not too sure I just made a taxonomy-product_cat.php which is where all this is sitting

Comment: I have update my answer so please check my **query** and in loop please do your HTML stuff there. And let me know if any query.

Comment: That has worked perfectly. my only problem is the permalink on the button it pulls with the product needs to go to that product page it seems <?php get_permalink(); ?> is not working

Comment: Use <?php echo get_the_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>

Comment: great thanks is there a <?php echo to pull a colour attribute into <p> tag

Comment: How to manage you color attribute in product ?

Comment: no just to show it on screen, i have set the attribute up for various sizes just not a colour

Comment: Please try this global $product; $color = $product->get_attribute( 'color' ); and echo in <p> tag

Comment: Fatal Error comes up

Comment: Check **echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'color', true);**

Comment: Still the same error

Comment: have you remove previous code?

Comment: The issue seems to be this line <?php global $product; $color = $product->get_attribute( 'colour' ); ?>

Comment: please removed it. and paste **echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'color', true);** in <p> tag

Comment: it removes the erro but does not show the attribute colour